# expo-router will not switch between 2 basic pages - Expo Router

Tags: reactjs, expo-router

I have created a basic expo-router project with `npx create-expo-app@latest --example with-router`. I moved to typescript by adding the `tsconfig.json`. In my `app` folder I have 2 files, `index.tsx` and `login.tsx`.

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Text>Index</Text>
      <Link href="/login">Login</Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

And

```
import { Text } from "react-native-paper";

export function Login() {
  return <Text>Login</Text>;
}
```

I am just wanting to navigate from the `index.tsx` to the `login` page. When I click the `Link`, I get an Unmatched Route page. I know this is supposed to be super simple, so what am I missing in my routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are defined by exporting a React component as the ***default*** value from a file in the app directory.

https://expo.github.io/router/docs/features/routing/